# JWT verification with jose is failing

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt

I have the following Next.js/Clerk.js middleware:

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { jwtVerify } from "jose";

export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/", "/contact", "/pricing", "/api/webhooks/user", "/api/reviews/add", "/api/user"],
  afterAuth (auth, req, evt) {
    const secret = new TextEncoder().encode (process.env.CLERK_PUBLIC_KEY)
    const decoded = jwtVerify ("eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkZXYiOiJkdmJfMlpFZkVyUG91dHBuaFptQXZzdk0zMkVadkVhIiwiaWQiOiJjbGllbnRfMlpFZkpieUFQUXRWbVB4Q3R2SER4SE04a2tCIiwicm90YXRpbmdfdG9rZW4iOiJmaWNid25rZDE0aTVpNm5rZzJicjc1ODl5NWZqeGloemloZDk2dnprIn0.qURs213vHtEe_2DTmOVN8jCPCJhQfIIEjWLMIXgIVYs86U1J3P5BV9EHexjvXda416D4wHAFdxUhUzjKj42CNM4TYTrrsXRT4m_fMNq78NrvwMf7ge2tmcSYNf04c7gqInQzJMNiKILZbQXN0yxExZ1lBbPesg-ZCsx5HZ1544-g0yrcZvxu7HkSwIG56C3ITae51rtMj4lpxyYUxdR9MZ0JZ-HH2XlCT_F3BMDUn_IHNXj2IDF6gI-1kx3UWwYZ5uCyTipbsuOwgFCINFA2m8h3IM0jS9KXGLNrixaej9M0uDEcYkxVRvSwNKJfeHmnhJefYEk82192XpmXJDft8Q", secret)
    console.log(decoded)
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

I'm using hose to verify a the JWT. But when the middleware is called I get an error:

```
Promise {
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 290979,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 290975,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: undefined,
  [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: {
  headers: [Getter],
  cookies: [Getter],
  mutableCookies: [Getter],
  draftMode: [Getter]
}
}
TypeError: Key for the RS256 algorithm must be of type CryptoKey. Received an instance of Uint8Array
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: something somewhere is receiving a `Uint8Array` instead of a `CryptoKey` - now since `TextEncoder#encode` will return a `Uint8Array` - my guess is that `secret` can't be `Uint8Array` when you use `RS256` algorithm for JWT - so, how did you create that JWT you're trying to verify? You would've have to have had a public/private key pair, right?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's generated from clerk. It's a clerk session token.

Comment: OK, so you need to supply the correct key pair used to create the JWT to verify it - you can't expect the verify process to magically guess the RSA keypair from the "secret" - oh, wait, just re-read the code ... still `new TextEncoder().encode` doesn't return a `CryptoKey` - I think you need to use jose's key import on `process.env.CLERK_PUBLIC_KEY` - maybe one of `jose.importSPKI` or `jose.importJWK` - whatever is appropriate for your particular situation

Answer (score 0):

Use the jose library like this. Look inside your JWT first, to get the correct algorithm from the JWT header, and the issuer / audience from the payload:

```js
import {createRemoteJWKSet, jwtVerify} from 'jose';

const jwksUri = 'https://api.clerk.dev/v1/jwks';
const jwks = createRemoteJWKSet(new URI(jwksUri));

async function validateJWT(accessToken: string): Promise<JwtClaims> {

  const options = {
    algorithms: ['RS256'],
    issuer: 'myissuer',
    audience: 'myaudience'
  };

  const result = await jwtVerify(accessToken, jwks, options);
  return result.payload
}
```

The first time you call `validateJWT` the library will download token signing public keys and cache them. This will simplify your code and also make it more resilient, since it will continue to work when clerk renews its token signing keypair.